# Selecionar todas as referências à determinada tabela (foreign key)

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Preciso de uma forma de selecionar todas as *foreign key* de uma determinada *pk*. Em outras palavras, eu quero pegar uma determinada *primary key* e selecionar todas as *foreign keys* que "apontam" para ela.

De preferência eu quero pegar o nome da **coluna** que tenha a chave, mas também pode ser o nome da chave mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode utilizar o seguinte select

```
select  r.owner, 
        r.table_name as tabela, 
        r.constraint_name as nome_chave,
        u.COLUMN_NAME
from  user_constraints r, 
      user_constraints o,
      user_cons_columns u
      where 
     r.r_owner = o.owner and 
     u.CONSTRAINT_NAME = r.CONSTRAINT_NAME and
      r.r_constraint_name = o.constraint_name and 
      o.constraint_type in ('P','U') and 
      r.constraint_type = 'R' and 
      o.table_name = '&NOME_DA_SUA_TABELA'
```

Baseado [Nesse](http://eduardolegatti.blogspot.com.br/2008/04/obtendo-informaes-de-relacionamentos.html) Artigo

Answer (score 2):

PLSQL Developer implementa a seguinte *query* para obter a lista de referências:

```
SELECT table_name, 
       constraint_name, 
       status, 
       owner 
FROM   all_constraints 
WHERE  r_owner = :r_owner 
       AND constraint_type = 'R' 
       AND r_constraint_name IN (SELECT constraint_name 
                                 FROM   all_constraints 
                                 WHERE  constraint_type IN ( 'P', 'U' ) 
                                        AND table_name = :r_table_name 
                                        AND owner = :r_owner) 
ORDER  BY table_name, 
          constraint_name
```

`:r_owner` é mencionado porque no Oracle `schema`s diferentes podem possuir tabelas diferentes que possuem o mesmo nome.

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143728/how-can-i-find-which-tables-reference-a-given-table-in-oracle-sql-developer